# how does " for (int j = 0; j < n || !putchar('\n'); j++) " work

Tags: c, boolean-expression

found this code that is responsible for printing out a two-dimensional array

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
 for (int j = 0; j < n || !putchar('\n'); j++)
  printf_s("%4d", A[i][j]);
```

how does boolean expression that causes printing out an escape sequence at the end of each row work?

Comment: Note that the title's `!putchar('\0')` (as opposed to `!putchar('\n')` in the text) would go into an infinite loop because putchar returns the character, in this case 0, and the negation operator turns it into `true`, so that the overall boolean value of `j < n || !putchar('\0')` is always `true`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two things in play here:

1. The [short-circuit evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) semantics of the logical AND and OR operators
2. That `!putchar('\n')` will always be "false" ([`putchar`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/putchar) returns either the character written or `EOF`, both are in this case non-zero and thus "true")

While `j < n` is true then the right-hand side of `||` will not be evaluated because of the short-circuit semantics. When `j < n` is false then `!putchar('\n')` will be evaluated, and it will print a newline and return a "true" value (either `'\n'` or `EOF` on error) which due to `!` becomes false so the whole condition becomes false and the loop ends.

It's an obfuscated variant of

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
    {
        printf_s("%4d", A[i][j]); 
    }
    putchar('\n');
}
```

I really recommend that you don't use (or worse, write) code as the one shown in the question. Obfuscation is not something to be proud of (unless you're entering into [the IOCCC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Obfuscated_C_Code_Contest)).

Comment: This short-cut with side-effects is more common in script languages like bash or perl where it is an idiom. In C* it can be a bit surprising to the casual reader.

Answer (score 6):

Because of `||`, the function `putchar` will only be called when `j < n` is false. Now, `j < n` is false at the end of every line. That's why you get `\n` at the end of every line.